# Converting 3" (No Trap) to Sink with Wall interference

Tags: plumbing, basement

Current Configuration:  3" (No Trap) pipe located in front of the future wall. (Blue Chalk line is the front edge of the wall (2x4).

Plan:  Repurpose this for the sink by 1. Breaking concrete, reduce the 3" to a 2" underground, then extending the underground pipe and turn it up so that it runs through stud for and up for the sink drain.

Question:  Is this okay to do per code? Is this the best way to do this?

[image: Existing Pipe & Future wall (blue)]

Comment: How are you planning to vent it? It's best to vent it through the roof but if you are using an AAV why not just use the current drain location with a reducer from the trap?

Comment: for venting:  I plan on venting to a nearby riser that goes to the ceiling, I will be also adding the venting for the toilet & shower which are on the opposite corner of the proposed bathroom.  (Note:  this is my inaugural attempt at plumbing so please pardon my ignorance any advice will be well received)